# Can't run test function in GoLand: cannot find package "."

Tags: go, jetbrains-ide, goland

I have used VS Code as my code editor for building service using Go for almost one year. Then, I tried to switch to GoLand. But, when I tried run a test function there is an error: `cannot find package "."` What is the problem?

Note: I use go module as go dependency management tool. When I use dep (in another project), there is no error when running a test function. My project is in GOPATH.

Comment: Do you use modules or vendored packages? Goland has its own notion of GOPATH and might not be using system environment one. Check in "Project preferences" -> "Go" -> "GOPATH" that either proper project GOPATH is set or "Use GOPATH that's defined in system enviornment" is checked.

Comment: I check "Enable vendoring support" in Go > Go Modules and I see that "Use GOPATH that's defined in system environment" is checked in Go > GOPATH.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure there's a valid `go.mod` file defined at the ROOT of your project i.e. in `$GOPATH/src/<Project-name>`.

If you don't have, you can create one using `go mod init` command using the shell. More information on the same - https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules

After that please try running the test from the shell. First `cd` into the directory where the test file is present. Then, use `go test . -test "<TestName>" -v` to run your test. If the issue goes away, you can run the test from IDE and it should work fine.